# Bot Framework does not notify about Telegram messages that begin with a mention

Tags: botframework, telegram-bot

I’m testing with the following setup: I have a bot with privacy mode disabled, so it listens to all messages in a channel. I have a webhook set in the Bot Framework that prints all incoming messages. I noticed the issue first on Telegram web and later discovered that it also affects Android, where you don’t get notifications only if you type a mention manually—if you select a mention from the drop-down, a notification gets sent.

Here are the screenshots of the channel where I was sending messages:

[image: telegram web]

[image: telegram android]

And here are the messages I got from the webhook:

```
new message: this message sent from web will be relayed even if it contains the mention @jlarky
new message: @JLarkyTestBot you can mention the bot though
new message: ^^ last message from web
new message: Now message from Android
new message: Yarosla mentions work
new message: Yarosla it has to be from mention dropdown, otherwise it's not sent either
```

As you can see, only a part of them was delivered.

Comment: Are you using .NET or Node SDK?

Comment: @NilsW neither, you can get exact same result if you put requestb.in url in the "Messaging endpoint", I'm talking about webhook not being called at all.